# Capture event when CustomDocumentProperties change in a Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in

I am developing an Add-in for Microsoft Word and Azure Information Protection. When a user is changing the classification of a document, the Azure Information Protection Add-in is updating CustomDocumentProperties in my Word document. I need to capture the event of changing the custom properties to act upon it and insert some text in the document.
Is there any way, to capture the event, when the properties are changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no event that's triggered within Word.

If the Add-in mentioned does not provide an interface that will let you pick this up, the only approach would be to save the values of the Custom Document Properties involved and periodically compare them to the current values.

Rather than manually writing text to the document you might consider using `{DocProperty}` fields nested in `{IF}` fields to dynamically generate the content. Then simply updating fields will show the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand "Rather than manually writing text to the document you might consider using {DocProperty} fields nested in {IF} fields to dynamically generate the content. Then simply updating fields will show the correct information." above you wrote.
Would you explain it more easily?